# Filtering string by range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How Can I filter string by range of numbers.

> Ex.: 0001 =< x =< 0010

where **x** is string: "AAA-SomeText-**0005**"

0001 - 0010 is range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following snippet for this. Let `stringList` be the list of string having input values:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>()
{
"AAA-SomeText-00015",
"AAA-SomeText-00025",
"AAA-SomeText-00019",
"AAA-SomeText-0005",
"AAA-SomeText-0006",
"AAA-SomeText-0007",
"AAA-SomeText-0008",
"AAA-SomeText-0009",
"AAA-SomeText-00010",
"AAA-SomeText-00011",
"AAA-SomeText-00012",
"AAA-SomeText-00013"
};
```

Then you will get the Filtered List by using the Following code:

```
int minRange = 1;
int maxRange = 10;
var subList = stringList.Select(x => new { index = int.Parse(x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("-") + 1)), value = x })
                        .Where(x => x.index > minRange && x.index < maxRange)
                        .Select(i=>i.value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>()
{
   "AAA-SomeText-00015",
   "AAA-SomeText-00025",
   "AAA-SomeText-00019",
   "AAA-SomeText-0005",
   "AAA-SomeText-0006",
   "AAA-SomeText-0007",
   "AAA-SomeText-0008",
   "AAA-SomeText-0009",
   "AAA-SomeText-00010",
   "AAA-SomeText-00011",
   "AAA-SomeText-00012",
   "AAA-SomeText-00013"
};

foreach (string text in stringList)
{
      if (int.Parse(text.Split('-')[2]) >= 0001 && int.Parse(text.Split('-')[2]) <= 0010)
      {
            // find filtered numbers
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split it by `-` and take the last value and compare that. Below is the snippet for that.

```
string strRange = "AAA-SomeText-0005";
int val = int.Parse(strRange.Split('-')[2]); //in val you get the last number.
```